# queries in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

have  to apply if  condition on JobSearchAgentID before returning  view

```
var res = (from results in db.JobSearchAgents
                            where results.SiteID == 110 && results.UserID == sess
                            select results).AsEnumerable().Select(results => new Agentlist
                            {
                                JobSearchAgentID = results.JobSearchAgentID.ToString(),

                                EmailAddress = results.EmailAddress,
                                Keywords = results.Keywords,


                                Country = results.Country,

                                zipcode = results.ZipCode,
                                miles = results.Miles.ToString()

                            });

            return View(res);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

you can go for an inline condition

```
 (from results in db.JobSearchAgents
                            where results.SiteID == 110 && results.UserID == sess
                            select results).AsEnumerable().Select(results => new Agentlist
                            {
                               //it is just an example
                                JobSearchAgentID =JobSearchAgentID!=null? results.JobSearchAgentID.ToString():[somthing else],

                                EmailAddress = results.EmailAddress,
                                Keywords = results.Keywords,

                                //another example
                                Country = String.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Country)?"No Country":results.Country,
                                //the last example
                                zipcode =results.Country=="United States"? "123": results.ZipCode,
                                miles = results.Miles.ToString()

                            });

            return View(res);
```

Comment: i have to check res.country=="" then what can i do

Comment: i have to check res.country=="uinited states"

Comment: and check if it is equal to united states then res.zipcode="123"

Comment: you can modify the condition. 

YourField=[predicate] ? [then] : [else]

Comment: i have to do something like this string country=res.country

Answer (score 0):

The query can be rewritten as:

```
var res = from results in db.JobSearchAgents
where results.SiteID == 110 && results.UserID == sess
select new Agentlist
{
    JobSearchAgentID = results.JobSearchAgentID.ToString(),
    EmailAddress = results.EmailAddress,
    Keywords = results.Keywords,
    Country = results.Country,
    zipcode = results.Country=="United States" ? "123" : results.ZipCode,
    miles = results.Miles.ToString()
});
string country = string.Emtpy;

foreach (var agentLst in res)
{
  country = agentLst.Country;     
}
```

My last answer was in the context of MVVM where we usually use ObservableCollection (present in System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace). Anyways I have updated my answer. This would work in your scenario.
Since the result of the linq query above is a collection (IEnumerable), hence you need to loop through it to get the data you need. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: it is missing assembly reference

Comment: it is showing type or namespace observable collection could not be found

Comment: it is showing the error only assignment,call increment,decrement,new object expression can be used as a statement